# Graph of function is compact

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that 
$\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ is a compact subset of $X\times\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

What i have done so far is :

$X$ is Hausdorff and $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff. So, $X\times \mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff.

Compact subset of Hausdorff space is closed.

Given that $\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ is a compact subset of $X\times\mathbb{R}$.

So,
$\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ is a closed subset of $X\times\mathbb{R}$.

Now, i am trying to prove that Graph is closed implies function is continuous..

I have checked some questions  in this site but they have mentioned just for metric spaces...

Please give only hints..

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Maybe this may help: using the fact that projections are continuous, you have that both $X$ and $f(X)$ are compact.

Comment: @Crostul : I saw that but could not use.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show for any open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals and a countable union of open sets is open, we just need to show $f^{-1}((a, b))$ is open in $X$.

To show this ,  by definition $f^{-1}((a, b))=\{x\in X: f(x)\in (a, b)\}$, the complement of it is $\{x: f(x)\geq b\}\cup\{x: f(x)\leq a\}$, let's show the complement is closed in $X$.

Notice that $X\times[ b,\infty)$ is closed in $X\times \mathbb{R}$, hence the intersection $(X\times [b, \infty))\cap\{(x, f(x)): x\in X\}=\{(x, f(x)): x\in X, f(x)\geq b\}$ is compact in $X\times \mathbb{R}$. Since the projection map is continuous, we have $\{x: f(x)\geq b\}$ is closed, so is $\{\{x: f(x)\leq a\}\}$.

Comment: I used the assumption that the graph is compact in the last equality.

Comment: YOu are awesome :D...  $X\times [b,\infty)$ is closed, $\{(x,f(x):x\in X)\}$ is closed so their intersection is closed... intersection is subset of $\{(x,f(x):x\in X)\}$.. closed subset of compact space is compact.. Here closedness is not sufficient as we are going to consider continous image... so, image under projection is compact.. Again compact subset of hausdorff space is closed so $\{x:f(x)\geq b\} $ is closed.. Similarly for $a$...